# General formal for complex symmetric part of sequence x[n]

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Given:

(1) **Complex Symmetric Sequence** has the property:

$$x[n]=x^{*}[-n]$$

What’s the general formula for the **Complex Symmetric Component** of the sequence x[n], in terms of x[n] and x*[n]?

I'm guessing it's this:

$$x_{complex\ symetric}[n] =\frac{1}{2}\left(x\left[n\right]+x^*\left[-n\right]\right)$$

How to prove this equation is true or false?

Comment: What does $\;x^*\;$ mean here? And what is $\;[n]\;$ ?

Comment: x*[n] means the complex conjugate of x[n].  if x[n]=a[n] + i b[n], then x*[n] = a[n] - i b[n].

Comment: x[n] means that its a discrete function, that is, its only defined at integer values of n.  This is in contrast to a continuous function: x(t) that can be defined at any real number t.

Comment: But then $\;-x^*[n]=-a[n]+ib[n] \neq a[n]+ib[n]\;$ ...! By the way, with $\;x[n]\;$, do you mean $\;x_n\;$ ?

Comment: And if $\;x\;$ is a function defined on integers or naturals,  what is the problem to denote its values by $\;x(n)\;$ instead of the confusing $\;x[n]\;$ ?

Comment: you can if you want to... its just a convention that's some DSP books follow by using square brackets when talking about discrete sequences, so that you don't mix it up with continuous time functions, which they also talk about sometimes.  I suppose, in most math books, they use subscripts instead of braces: $$x_n$$ when referring to sequences. but the EE textbooks prefer square braces.

Comment: Anyway, your first equality is false in general...or should we understand that the function ( or sequence... $\;x[n]$ ) fulfills that equality?

Comment: the textbook implies that its true in the question, however, I'm not really sure where they came up with this equation... I couldn't say for certain its true for every sequence of x[n]..  There's a similar relationship that exists for even/odd components of a sequence... i'm guessing the point of the question is to show you that a similar relationship exists for complex conjugate symmetric funcitons..but they don't really talk about it in the textbook...

Comment: I really can't understand what you, or that textbook, is saying: it is clear that first relation is false as given, so....what? That seems to be a function $\;x:\Bbb N\to\Bbb C\;$ , and clearly not all such functions fulfill that.

Comment: my conclusion is that even sequence doesn't always equal the complex conjugate sequence.  the book just asserts that the even sequence equals the complex conjugate sequence for a particular type of sequence.  then provides the general formula for complex conjugate sequence as a subset of a sequence. if that makes sense... anyways... still a little bit shakey on that one...

Comment: If you want to take a look at the book its: "Schaum's outline: Digital Signal Processing", Second Edition, page 20, problem 1.5.  if I look at problem 1.6. the even part of the function is something like "j cos(nw)", but the complex conjugate part is "0".... eventhough they equate the complex conjugate sequence to the even sequence, obviously not true.

Comment: I've figured out what the problem is with those questions in the book, its a typographical error.  they printed $$x_{e}(n)$$ instead of $$x_{c}(n)$$ which confuses the heck out of you...

Comment: For $x[n]$ a sequence we look at its Fourier transform $f(t) = \sum_n x[n] e^{2i \pi n t}$ (if $\sum_n |x[n]| < \infty$ then $f$ is continuous). Then $x[n] = a[n]+i b[n], a[n] = \frac{x[n]+x[-n]^*}{2} = a[-n]^*,b[n] =-i \frac{x[n]-x[-n]^*}{2} = b[-n]^*$ so that $f(t) = g(t)+i h(t)$ where $g,h$ are real and are the FT of $a[n],b[n]$. @DonAntonio

Comment: @reuns Thanks. That was waaaaay away from what I thought! I had no idea Fourier series and stuff were included in this, in particular because of the question's tagging and the almost complete lack of explanations.

Answer (score 0):

A **Conjugate Symmetric Sequence** (CSS) is defined as:

$$x[n] = x^{*}[-n]$$

A **Anti-Conjugate Symmetric Sequence** (CAS) is defined as:

$$x[n] = - x^{*}[-n]$$

It can be shown that any sequence can be written as the sum of an CSS sequence and an CAS sequence as follows:

$$x[n] =  x_{css}[n] + x_{cas}[n] $$

$$x[n] = (0.5)(x[n] + X^{*}[-n]) + (0.5)(x[n] - X^{*}[-n])$$

$$x[n] = x[n] $$

we can see that CSS Sequence is equal to:

$$x_{css}[n] = (0.5) (x[n] + x^{*}[n])$$